# Cordova/iOS: How to close native browser window opened with InAppBrowser?

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am opening a URL in the `_system` browser, which redirects back to the app (using a custom URL scheme). Once back in the app, I would like to close the external browser window, but it doesn't work.

```
var iab = window.open(url, '_system', 'location=no');
...
iab.close(); // log: "IAB.close() called but it was already closed."
```

It closes in-app browser windows, but not `_system` windows. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Same problem still in 2019 :( Any idea?

Comment: No, it seems apps are not allowed to close system browser windows. It makes sense... `window.open` doesn't really open another Web view in your app - it asks the system to launch a different app. We're not allowed to mess with other apps' windows.

Answer (score -3):

Use iframe on target page.

```
var iab = window.open(url, '_system', 'location=no');
```

Url redirect to page, who has iframe and close by timeout.

```
<iframe src="myurl://..."></iframe>

setTimeout(function()
{
    window.close();
},1000);
```